# How to get glowing effect with css

Tags: html, css, web

Whats the best way you would suggest getting a glowing effect around a div of text? Can it be done through CSS?

I tried playing around with the box-shadow but couldn't quite get it how I wanted it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you mean a glow on the text itself or in a rectangle around the text?

Comment: _couldn't quite get it how I wanted it_ How did you want it? You need to be specific. Include an MCVE like Paulie_D said and explain how what you did is different from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `text-shadow` - see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-textshadow for info on what browsers support it, and the "Resources" tab there for links about how to use it

Comment: The OP wants the glow around the div, not the text.

Comment: Not clear - they did say `box-shadow` didn't do what they wanted. Asking for clarification

Comment: They said they couldn't get it 'quite' right. Without the code they tried I don't know what they wanted it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px -1px rgba(0,255,81,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px -1px rgba(0,255,81,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px -1px rgba(0,255,81,1);
```

Just play around with the controls at http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow until you get what you want.

```css
div {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px -1px rgba(0,255,81,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px -1px rgba(0,255,81,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px -1px rgba(0,255,81,1);
  }
```

```html
<div><p>Text</p></div>
```